# Can PHPCrawl can be used for scraping websites and how different is from Scrapy?

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy, phpcrawl

I want to scrape few websites and many suggested `Scrapy`. It is Python based and since I am very familiar with PHP I looked for alternatives.

I got a crawler `PHPCrawl`. I am not sure if it is just a crawler or will it provides scraping facility as well. If it can be used for scraping- will it support XPath or Regular expressions.

How can it be compared with `Scrapy` which is on Python.

Please suggest me which is best to use for scraping the websites.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHPCrawl is a pure crawler, it delivers found pages and their sourcecode to users "as they are" (together with some context-information). Therefor it's fast, it's able ot use multi processes and has tons of options to configure it.

Can't say much about Scrapy since i didn't use it so far.

Comment: Thanks but what I need to know is- can PHPCrawl be used for scraping ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course.
But as i said, PHPCrawl delivers the page-sources, and you have to extract the data you want to extract from it.

Comment: If it delivers the page source, i can use DOMObject and get the details. BUT this can also achieved using file_get_contents() in other way. what for phpcrawl is usefull if it provides only the page source and no inbuilt methods for using xpaths...

Comment: It's a webcrawler, file_get_contents isn't ;) If you just want to get the source of a single page then you'll be fine with file_get_contents().